# Fastest way to test a 128 bit NEON register for a value of 0 using intrinsics?

Tags: neon

I'm looking for the fastest way to test if a 128 NEON register contains all zeros, using NEON intrinsics.
I'm currently using 3 OR operations, and 2 MOVs:

```
uint32x4_t vr = vorrq_u32(vcmp0, vcmp1);

uint64x2_t v0 = vreinterpretq_u64_u32(vr);
uint64x1_t v0or = vorr_u64(vget_high_u64(v0), vget_low_u64(v0));

uint32x2_t v1 = vreinterpret_u32_u64 (v0or);
uint32_t r = vget_lane_u32(v1, 0) | vget_lane_u32(v1, 1);

if (r == 0) { // do stuff }
```

This translates by gcc to the following assembly code:

```
VORR     q9, q9, q10
VORR     d16, d18, d19
VMOV.32  r3, d16[0]
VMOV.32  r2, d16[1]
VORRS    r2, r2, r3
BEQ      ...
```

Does anyone have an idea of a faster way?

Answer (score 8):

While this answer may be a bit late, there is a simple way to do the test with only 3 instructions and no extra registers:

```
inline uint32_t is_not_zero(uint32x4_t v)
{
    uint32x2_t tmp = vorr_u32(vget_low_u32(v), vget_high_u32(v));
    return vget_lane_u32(vpmax_u32(tmp, tmp), 0);
}
```

The return value will be nonzero if any bit in the 128-bit NEON register was set.

Comment: instead of the second line, you could simply convert tmp to uint64_t. `return (uint64_t)tmp;` should work.

Answer (score 3):

If you're targeting AArch64 NEON, you can use the following to get a value to test with just two instructions:

```
inline uint64_t is_not_zero(uint32x4_t v)
{
    uint64x2_t v64 = vreinterpretq_u64_u32(v);
    uint32x2_t v32 = vqmovn_u64(v64);
    uint64x1_t result = vreinterpret_u64_u32(v32);
    return result[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for intrinsics and this is the way:

```
inline bool is_zero(int32x4_t v) noexcept
{
  v = v == int32x4{};

  return !int32x2_t(
    vtbl2_s8(
      int8x8x2_t{
        int8x8_t(vget_low_s32(v)),
        int8x8_t(vget_high_s32(v))
      },
      int8x8_t{0, 4, 8, 12}
    )
  )[0];
}
```

Nils Pipenbrinck's answer has a flaw in that he assumes the QC, cumulative saturation flag to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you have AArch64 you can do it even easier. They have a new instruction for designed for this.

```
inline uint32_t is_not_zero(uint32x4_t v)
{
    return vaddvq_u32(v);
}
```

Comment: This seems vulnerable to overflows, though.

Comment: If you are using the full 32 bit, yes, it can wrap around and cause a false positive, but if you know your numbers are smaller than 2³²/4 it is safe.

Comment: Probably better though to just use vmaxvq_u32 then. A similar reduction instruction, but one returning the maximum value instead of the sum.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid functions returning integer values that should only be interpreted as bool. A better way would be, for instance, defining a helper function to return maximum unsigned value of 4 lanes:

```
inline uint32_t max_lane_value_u32(const uint32x4_t& v)
{
#if defined(_WIN32) && defined(_ARM64_)
    // Windows 64-bit
    return neon_umaxvq32(v);
#elif defined(__LP64__)
    // Linux/Android 64-bit
    return vmaxvq_u32(v);
#else
    // Windows/Linux/Android 32-bit
    uint32x2_t result = vmax_u32(vget_low_u32(v), vget_high_u32(v));
    return vget_lane_u32(vpmax_u32(result, result), 0);
#endif
}
```

you can then use:

```
if (0 == max_lane_value_u32(v))
{
    ...
}
```

in your code, and such function might also be useful elsewhere. Alternatively, you can use the exact same code to write a **is_not_zero()** function, but then it's best form to return a **bool**.

Note that the only reason you'd need to define a helper function is because vmaxvq_u32() is not available on 32-bit, and may not be aliased from neon_umaxvq32() in arm64_neon.h on Windows.