# Optimizing horizontal boolean reduction in ARM NEON

Tags: arm, simd, neon

I'm experimenting with a cross-platform SIMD library ala [ecmascript_simd aka SIMD.js](https://github.com/johnmccutchan/ecmascript_simd), and part of this is providing a few "horizontal" SIMD operations. In particular, the API that library offers includes `any(<boolN x M>) -> bool` and `all(<boolN x M>) -> bool` functions, where `<T x K>` is a vector of `K` elements of type `T` and `boolN` is an `N`-bit boolean, i.e. all ones or all zeros, as SSE and NEON return for their comparison operations.

For example, let `v` be a `<bool32 x 4>` (a 128-bit vector), it could be the result of [`VCLT.S32`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489i/ch05s144.html) or something. I'd like to compute `all(v) = v[0] && v[1] && v[2] && v[3]` and `any(v) = v[0] || v[1] || v[2] || v[3]`.

This is easy with SSE, e.g. [`movmskps`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVMSKPS.html) will extract the high bit of each element, so `all` for the type above becomes (with C intrinsics):

```
#include<xmmintrin.h>
int all(__m128 x) {
    return _mm_movemask_ps(x) == 8 + 4 + 2 + 1;
}
```

and similarly for `any`.

I'm struggling to find obvious/nice/efficient ways to implement this with NEON, which doesn't support an instruction like `movmskps`. There's the approach of simply extracting each element and computing with scalars. E.g. there's the naive method but there's also the approach of using the "horizontal" operations NEON supports, like [`VPMAX` and `VPMIN`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489i/ch05s144.html).

```
#include<arm_neon.h>

int all_naive(uint32x4_t v) {
    return v[0] && v[1] && v[2] && v[3];
}
int all_horiz(uint32x4_t v) {
    uint32x2_t x = vpmin_u32(vget_low_u32(v),
                             vget_high_u32(v));
    uint32x2_t y = vpmin_u32(x, x);
    return x[0] != 0;
}
```

(One can do a similar thing for the latter with [`VPADD`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489i/ch05s144.html), which may be faster, but it's fundamentally the same idea.)

Are there are other tricks one can use to implement this?

---

Yes, I know that horizontal operations are not great with SIMD vector units. But sometimes it is useful, e.g. many SIMD implementations of mandlebrot will operate on 4 points at once, and bail out of the inner loop when all of them are out of range... which requires doing a comparison and then a horizontal and.

Comment: The more interesting SSE instruction to `movemskps` is `ptest`. You can use this for `and` or `or`. I think Neon has the same instruction `vtest`. I have not implemented this yet but I think you can find your answer here [fastest-way-to-test-a-128-bit-neon-register-for-a-value-of-0-using-intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389539/fastest-way-to-test-a-128-bit-neon-register-for-a-value-of-0-using-intrinsics).

Comment: @Zboson: `vtst` turns out to not be especially useful here, sadly (because you already have a vector of 0/-1 values from the compare).  Nils' suggestion from the linked answer (saturated add + read Q bit) doesn't work out nicely in general because the Q bit is sticky so you need to clear it first with RMW.  So the usual approach is multiple `vpmax`/`vpmin` on arm32 and a single `umaxv`/`uminv` on arm64.

Comment: I was not aware that many "SIMD implementations of mandlebrot will operate on 4 points at once, and bail out of the inner loop when all of them are out of range..." I have been doing this for awhile myself (actually 8 pixels with AVX for single float). For x86 I use `ptest` but it appears you have already found the best solution with ARM: namely min/max twice with arm7 and once with arm8.

Comment: @StephenCanon, in that case maybe you can provide an answer to [fastest-way-to-test-a-128-bit-neon-register-for-a-value-of-0-using-intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389539/fastest-way-to-test-a-128-bit-neon-register-for-a-value-of-0-using-intrinsics).

Comment: Related: [NEON pack vector compare result into bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568992/neon-pack-vector-compare-result-into-bitmap) asks for a `movmskps` equivalent.  Might not be the right building block for things like testing if any element was true, though.  (e.g. only packing down to 4 bytes instead of 4 bits may be easier, and testing a 32-bit integer for 0 or -1)

Answer (score 2):

This is my current solution that is implemented in [eve library](https://github.com/jfalcou/eve).

If your backend has C++20 support, you can just use the library: it has implementations for arm-v7, arm-v8 (only little endian at the moment) and all x86 from sse2 to avx-512. It's open source and MIT licensed. In beta at the moment. Feel free to reach out (for example with an issue) if you are trying out the library.

Take everything with a grain of salt - **I don't yet have the arm benchmarks set up**.

*NOTE: On top of basic all and any we also have a `movemask` equivalent to do more complex operations like `first_true`. That wasn't part of the question and it's not amazing but the code can be found [here](https://github.com/jfalcou/eve/blob/3ef17b7ed8b69368c55959d4c63027b6735fd740/include/eve/detail/function/simd/arm/neon/movemask.hpp#L52)*

**ARM-V7, 8 bytes register**

Now, arm-v7 is 32 bit architecture, so we try to get to 32 bit elements where we can.

- any

Use pairwise 32 bit max. If any element is true, the max is true.

```
// cast to dwords
dwords = vpmax_u32(dwords, dwords);
return vget_lane_u32(dwords, 0);
```

- all

Pairwise min instead of max. Also what you test against changes.
If you have 4 byte element - just test for true. If shorts or chars - you need to test for -1;

```
// cast to dwords
dwords = vpmin_u32(dwords, dwords);
std::uint32_t combined = vget_lane_u32(dwords, 0);

// Assuming T is your scalar type
if constexpr ( sizeof(T) >= 4 ) return combined;

// I decided that !~ is better than -1, compiler will figure it out.
return !~combined;
```

**ARM-V7, 16 bytes register**

For anything bigger than chars, just do a conversion to a 64 bit one. Here is the list of [vector narrow integer](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0491/h/Using-NEON-Support/Converting-vectors) conversions.

For chars, the best I found is to reinterpret as uint32 and do an extra check.
So compare for == -1 for all and > 0 for any.
Seemed nicer asm the split in two 8 byte registers.

Then just do all/any on that dword register.

**ARM-v8, 8 byte**

ARM-v8 has 64 bit support, so you can just get a 64 bit lane. That one is trivially testable.

**ARM-v8, 16 byte**

We use `vmaxvq_u32` since there is not a 64 bit one for `any` and `vminvq_u32`, `vminvq_u16` or `vminvq_u8` for `all` depending on the element size.
(Which is similar to [glibc strlen](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/aarch64/multiarch/strlen_asimd.S.html))

**Conclusion**

Lack of benchmarks definitely makes me worried, some instructions are problematic sometimes and I don't know about it.
Regardless, that's the best I've got, so far at least.

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: first time looking at arm today, I might be wrong about things.*

**UPD: Removed ARM-V7 and will write up what we ended up doing in a separate answer**

**ARM-V8.**

For ARM-V8, have a look at this strlen implementation from glibc:
https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/aarch64/multiarch/strlen_asimd.S.html

ARM-V8 introduced reductions across registers. Here they use min to compare with 0

```
        uminv        datab2, datav.16b
        mov          tmp1, datav2.d[0]
        cbnz         tmp1, L(main_loop)
```

Find the smallest char, compare with 0 - take the next 16 bytes.

There are a few other reductions in ARM-V8 like `vaddvq_u8`.
I'm pretty sure you can do most of the things you'd want from `movemask` and alike with this.

Another interesting thing here is how they find the `first_true`

```
        /* Set te NULL byte as 0xff and the rest as 0x00, move the data into a
           pair of scalars and then compute the length from the earliest NULL
           byte.  */
        cmeq        datav.16b, datav.16b, #0
        mov        data1, datav.d[0]
        mov        data2, datav.d[1]
        cmp        data1, 0
        csel        data1, data1, data2, ne
        sub        len, src, srcin
        rev        data1, data1
        add        tmp2, len, 8
        clz        tmp1, data1
        csel        len, len, tmp2, ne
        add        len, len, tmp1, lsr 3
```

Looks a bit intimidating, but my understanding is:

1. they narrow it down to a 64 bit number just by doing if/else (if the first half doesn't have the zero - the second half does.
2. use count leading zeroes to find the position (didn't quite understand all of the endianness stuff here but it's libc - so this is the correct one).

So - if you only need V8 - there is a solution.

Comment: rev/clz implements count *trailing* zeros in terms of clz because ARM/AArch64 don't have a direct equivalent for x86 `bsf` / `tzcnt`.  (This is what you want to find the lowest-address match in the vector, on a little-endian system like x86 or AArch64.)  RBIT / CLZ is the standard implementation / emulation for __builtin_ctz, but if you know all bits in a byte are identical then REV works, too.  Most of the rest of the code is just branchless handling of the +8 or +0 to match up with the data section your described as part 1.  (`cinc` / `csinc` can only add 1, not 8, so add/csel is good.)

Comment: One reason not to use something like this for 32-bit ARM code is that some ARM pipelines have big stalls when integer instructions read a value from SIMD registers.  So even if you could branch on a SIMD compare in a couple instructions, that might be slower.

Comment: @PeterCordes how about the `reverse` idea for armv7? Is that good?

Comment: IDK, I'm not that familiar with ARM myself.  [Perform a horizontal logical/bitwise AND operation across all lanes of uint8x8 Neon vector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46911053) is I think related; Jake has posted many good ARM asm answers with useful tricks like that.  Including [NEON pack vector compare result into bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46744768) to emulate x86 movmskps (4x 4-byte elements -> 4 bits).