# How to OR all lane of a NEON vector

Tags: arm, intrinsics, neon

I want to use NEON intrinsics to optimize the following code.

```
uint32x4_t c1; // 4 elements, each element is 0 or 1
uint32x4_t c2; // 4 elements, each element is 0 or 1
uint8_t pack = 0; // unsigned char, for result

/* some code /*

// need optimizing
pack |= (vgetq_lane_u32(c1, 0);
pack |= (vgetq_lane_u32(c1, 1) << 1;
pack |= (vgetq_lane_u32(c1, 2) << 2;
pack |= (vgetq_lane_u32(c1, 3) << 3;


pack |= (vgetq_lane_u32(c2, 0) << 4;
pack |= (vgetq_lane_u32(c2, 1) << 5;
pack |= (vgetq_lane_u32(c2, 2) << 6;
pack |= (vgetq_lane_u32(c2, 3) << 7;
```

I think need some intrinsics to OR all lanes of a vector.
Could anybody give me some hints ?

Comment: Normally for associative horizontal reductions like ADD or OR, you extract the high half to and combine, then repeat until you're down to a single element.  Takes log2( N_elements ) steps.  And of course you vertically combine your two vectors down to one vector before you start halving the width with horizontal ops.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you want a different shift count for each lane, so you want to pack 8x 32-bit `bool` elements into a bitmap.  My comment previous comment was based on the title.  And BTW, if you actually have 0/-1 vector compare result vectors, you might use [NEON pack vector compare result into bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568992/neon-pack-vector-compare-result-into-bitmap) instead of masking them with `& 1` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shift each element within a vector by individual amount of bits.

```
const int32x4_t shifter1 = {0, 1, 2, 3};
const int32x4_t shifter2 = {4, 5, 6, 7};
.
.
.
c1 = vshlq_u32(c1, shifter1);
c2 = vshlq_u32(c2, shifter2);

c1 = vorrq_u32(c1, c2);
pack |= vgetq_lane_u32(c1, 0) | vgetq_lane_u32(c1, 1) | vgetq_lane_u32(c1, 2) | vgetq_lane_u32(c1, 3);
```

That should do the trick, and the last line is up to the quality of your compiler

Comment: `pack=0` initially, so you can write `pack = ...` instead of `pack |= ...`.  The OP was just being weird in using `|=` even for the first SIMD element.

Comment: @PeterCordes `/* some code */` should contain that part. :-)

Comment: Intrinsic vgetq_lane is slow, I don't want to use it.

Comment: @shang12 `vgetq_lane` isn't slow, but yes, it comes with a huge latency of roughly 14 cycles (`vmov` to ARM registers) . It all comes down to the next step. If you need `pack` as `uint8_t` that you can do further computations on, there is no way around. If you just want to store it to the memory, it makes sense keeping it in NEON register. And since you declared `pack` as `uint8_t`, the latter didn't seem viable to me. The answer can only get as good as your question. Nobody can read or guess your mind online.

Comment: I am calculating a binary image. Each loop will produce a pixel (0 or 1), and I am going to pack 8 pixel in one byte. Thank for your help ! I will use this solution.