# Perform a horizontal logical/bitwise AND operation across all lanes of uint8x8 Neon vector

Tags: arm, simd, neon

I have a `uint8x8` Neon vector which is a result of some operation. I need to perform a logical `AND` operation of the all the lanes to get my final result. Each element is either `0xff` (TRUE) or `0x00` (FALSE). How do I perform it in Neon?

Comment: What are the values in each element ? 1 and 0, or 0xff and 0, or just non-zero and 0 ?

Comment: It is either 0xff or 0x00..

Comment: In that case just use a bitwise AND, i.e. [`VAND`](https://developer.arm.com/docs/dui0472/l/using-neon-support/neon-intrinsics-for-logical-operations).

Comment: Hi paul, I need to perform on the lanes. VAND is for bitwise operation on two vectors right?  My requirement is to AND lane0, lane1, lane2....lane7.

Comment: I know that I can get the individual lane using   vgetq_lane and then perform AND as a non-NEON computation. Just looking for a better way. Like there us pairwise ADD in NEON but pairwise logical operations are not there.

Comment: Oh, something just occurred to me: you're not trying to do a *horizontal* AND operation, are you ? You should make this clear in the question.

Comment: I am looking for lane0 & lane1 & lane2 & lane3 & lane4 & lane5 & lane6 & lane7 ; So that result will be a scalar value of uint8_t.

Comment: OK - that is a *horizontal* operation then. You can do this by shifting by 1, 2, 4 elements and applying [`VAND`](https://developer.arm.com/docs/dui0472/l/using-neon-support/neon-intrinsics-for-logical-operations) (6 instructions in total). Or, if this is just a final operation after a loop (and therefore not performance-critical) then you can just do it in scalar code.

Comment: Thanks Paul. It is a performance critical operation.

Comment: OK - so use the 6 instruction sequence I described above then. I don't know of any more efficient way with Neon (although you might be able to something clever with horizontal additions).

Comment: @PaulR: If NEON has efficient horizontal sums, yeah you could check that the hsum == `-1 * element_count`.  Nice idea.  (BTW, x86 could do this very efficiently with pcmpeq / pmovmsk / compare+branch, but as I understand it, ARM doesn't have anything like x86's pmovmsk or ptest.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: yes, I haven't done any Neon for quite a while now, but I know there are some horizontal (pairwise) add operations. There may even be one which adds 4 adjacent elements, but I can't find it just now.

Comment: What form do you need the result in?  Do you need to branch on it (thus scalar integer / boolean condition)?  Or can you more efficiently use zero / -1 in a SIMD register?

Comment: @PeterCordes NEON has horizontal pairwise maximum and minimum (signed and unsigned) operations on 8-, 16- and 32-bit integers. I'd say `vpmin.u8/vpmin.u16/vpmin.u32` should give the result in three instructions + moving the result to memory or the integer core (the expensive part).

Comment: @EOF: Nice, unsigned min should work even on AArch64 where you can't AND together the two `s` register halves of the 64-bit `d` register.  If you're moving to integer, you only need `vpmin.u32` and then you can compare against a 32-bit `-1`

Comment: @PeterCordes And since `mov` from NEON registers to ARM registers doesn't set flags, the comparison against `-1` is no worse than against `0`.

Comment: @EOF NEON compare instructions accept zero as an immediate value and NOTHING else. That's a HUGE difference.

Comment: @EOF And `aarch64` features a dedicated zero register `xzr/wzr`, and depending on circumstances, the compiler can translate the comparison to other, more efficient computations leveraging this. Summing it up, zero is something very special on each and every architecture, and should be preferred over other numbers even while programming in higher level languages.

Answer (score 2):

In that case, you can simply do a binary negation, and check if the 64bit result is 0.

```
vmvn d0, d0    
vpaddl.u32 d0, d0 // 64bit vceq isn't possible.
vceq.i32 d0, d0, #0
```

You now have the desired result in d0.

If you are working on `aarch64`, 64bit `cmeq` is possible

```
mvn v0.16b, v0.16b
cmeq v0.2d, v0.2d, #0
```

The best thing about this algorithm is that you don't need any other registers, because zero is the only immediate value accepted by the compare instructions.

Comment: Related: [Optimizing horizontal boolean reduction in ARM NEON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31197216) suggest AArch64 `uminv` for a horizontal boolean reduction between 0xff and 0x00 bytes.  Is that useful here, where I guess the OP wants the result in a vector, not integer reg?

Comment: the `b0` register overlaps with `q0`, `d0`, `s0`, and `h0`, and is located at `v0[0]`. So I think it will work. But I don't think `uminv` is a single cycle instruction. I might be wrong.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE - my answer was from gcc strlen implementation: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/aarch64/multiarch/strlen_asimd.S.html#93
still doesn't guarantee it's good though.

Answer (score 1):

Simple/obvious method (pseudo-code):

```
v = VAND(v, v >> 8)
v = VAND(v, v >> 16)
v = VAND(v, v >> 32)
```

3 x shifts and 3 x bitwise ANDs = 6 instructions.

---

Possibly more efficient method: do a horizontal sum of all elements, then return `TRUE` if `sum == -8`, otherwise return `FALSE`.

---

Possibly simpler method: just compare vector with a vector of all 1s.

```
return v == 0xffffffffffffffff;
```

Doing this efficiently is left as an exercise for the reader (may require 2 x 32 bit compares ?).

Comment: You could stop at a 32-bit element and compare it against 0xFFFFFF.  If you eventually need the result as scalar integer, I assume getting a 32-bit integer from NEON to integer is just as efficient as 8-bit.    (Do the `v>>32` first, to narrow by half the interesting part of the data at each step.  On AArch32, this would be an AND between the two 32-bit halves of the 64-bit register, so there's no actual shift instruction.)

Comment: D'oh - I just realised you can do the whole thing with a single compare !

Comment: Oh, it has 64-bit element size compares?  d'oh here too.

Comment: Oops no - only 32 bit compares - I take it back. (Time to step away from the computer and get some coffee I think...)

Comment: I vote for `-1 == high(v) & low(v);` on AArch64 that should be one shift, one AND, and one compare.  (Actually on AArch64, probably you can extract 64 bits directly to an integer reg and compare against -1?)  But on AArch32 it's a 32-bit AND between the two component registers.

Comment: Thanks you Paul and Peter. I would try 3 x shifts and 3 x bitwise ANDs = 6 instruction as Paul has suggested

Comment: Related: [Optimizing horizontal boolean reduction in ARM NEON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31197216) suggest `uminv` for a horizontal boolean reduction between 0xff and 0x00 bytes.